# keep opened submenu after mouseout from parent in jQuery

Tags: jquery, submenu

I have made a horizontal menu that contains images and text.
However, I used this code to show and hide it's submenu:

```
$('#top_menu').hover(function(e) {
    $('#about_submenu').fadeIn('slow');
},function(){
    $('#about_submenu').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Everything works fine, but whenever I move the mouse from parent to its submenu, the submenu disappears because of `fadeOut`. How can I keep submenu appearing when I move cursor from parent link position?

Comment: Create a fiddle first.. that should Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#top_menu').hover(function(e) {
    if(!$('#about_submenu').is(':visible'))
    {
        $('#about_submenu').fadeIn('slow');
    }
},function(){
    if(!$('#about_submenu').is(':hover'))
    {
        $('#about_submenu').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});

$('#about_submenu').mouseout(function(){
    if(!$('#top_menu').is(':hover'))
    {
        $('#about_submenu').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the fadeout with a small timeout, like 200ms. Cancel the fadeout if you hover a submenu item.

Here is an example in terms of the code that you already have:

```
var timeoutID;
$('#top_menu').hover(function(e) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    $('#about_submenu').fadeIn('slow');
},function(){
    timeoutID = setTimeout(hideSubmenu, 200);
});

$('#about_submenu').hover(function(e) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
},function(){
    timeoutID = setTimeout(hideSubmenu, 200);
});

function hideMenu() {
    $('#about_submenu').fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Comment: @MohammadSaberi There you go.

Comment: How did you canceled fadeOut if cursor is on submenu here?

Comment: @MohammadSaberi The hideMenu function would not execute because the timeout is cleared.

Comment: What will happen if the user hovers on the #top_menu, then move mouse out of it and then back to the #top_menu within 200 ms. Will the timeout be cleared? and if not then will the menu hide back?

Comment: I updated with a more complete example below and using the code in the question

Comment: Now you are clearing timeout on mouseover also so I think this should work :)

Comment: I made it using CSS, Ul and Li tags finally